# Colored logcat in android studio by colorpid

Tags: android-studio

according to this link [github colored logcat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) I am looking for any solution how to use it in android studio/intellij. Is there in android studio any option to modify calling `adb logcat`?
Here is the example how it works.
[image]

Comment: could you change these colours in Terminal? My Terminal is having completely other (boring) colours in comparing with this screenshot :(

Comment: Another color scheme can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39993868/619673

Answer (score 412, accepted):

You can customize colors at `Preferences – Editor – Color Scheme – Android Logcat`.

[image: Android logcat color editor]

Here is Darcula theme, suggested by [Matouš Skála](https://plus.google.com/106469676501590767654/posts/VJhgiXmTM3f):

Darcula colors:

```
Debug  : 6897BB
Info   : 6A8759
Warn   : BBB529
Error  : FF6B68
Assert : 9876AA
```

[image: Darcula theme]

`Only show logcat from selected process` is supported by default feature at AndroidStudio. If you are not satisfied with current customizations you need to continue to use your favorite shell with JakeWharton srcipt as for now.

Comment: this little details increase productivity **so** much, google should add this detail as a default.

Comment: I was wondering eclipse ADT was having a better Logcat display than IntelliJ, but Wow! after I applied custom colors it even looks better than the Eclipse Logcat. Thanks for this info. :-)

Comment: I was using Android Device Monitor just because of the colors. Now I can stay inside Android Studio. Thanks for this answer, now life is a little better.

Comment: It seems that the menus are different from Android Studio **1.1.0**. I am posting a new answer regarding the same

Comment: Here are the colors from the middle screenshot: assert #AE92B0 error #F8837F warn #C6C246 info #759769 debug #8FB8D0

Comment: Colours from bottom screenshot - Debug=#54C1E9, Info=#8CD10D, Warn=#FAC848, Error=#F95C5A, Assert=#B87BD5. Note that if you want to keep the rest of your IDE with a white background you should modify a light (e.g. Default) theme and set the background for the Android Logcat settings (Background=#393939).

Comment: Any ways to change the color of a link. It shows as an unreadable blue color.

Comment: Very helpful. For Intellij IDEA,go to File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->Android Logcat.

Comment: Requested as new default in Android Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37898663

Answer (score 21):

As of Android Studio 1.1.0 the `Preferences` menu was not visible in the menu bar *(Atleast in Ubuntu)*. So I am posting a new answer that might help others:

Goto **`File`** ❯ **`Settings`** or press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**S**</kbd> this will open the **Settings** dialog *(see screenshot)*

Now under **`IDE Settings`** navigate to **`Editor`**❯**`Colors & Fonts`**❯**`Android Logcat`** you can customize the colors of your choice.

**NOTE:** make sure you un-check the `Inherit Attributes From:` checkbox in order to edit the scheme.

[image: Settings Dialog]

Answer (score 11):

If you already use [Solarized Dark](https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/) elsewhere, try these with Darcula:

```
Verbose   657B83
Debug     93A1A1
Info      22AAAA
Warning   B58900
Error     CB4B16
Assert    6C71C4
```

[image: Preview of Solarized color scheme on background of dark grey.]

Answer (score 1):

You can download this files [filesCustomAndroidStudio](https://github.com/elabi3/AndroidStudioTemplates) and copy in

Mac: /Users/.../Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioXX.XX/ Windows: C:\Users....AndroidStudioXX.XX\config\

Then go to logcat in settings and choose the file.