# Android Studio Logcat colors

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, logcat

It is really hard to follow up Android logcat output all in a same color.

Is there any way to change the log colors?

Comment: Have been barred from asking questions (for reasons unknown to me). So I ask one through the comments: How can you set the text color for the expression "Log" in the code itself (so you can clearly see where you put logs in your code)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe there is such an option in the IDE to change logs color in the code. Maybe you can find a plugin that allows Regex coloring!

Answer (score 272, accepted):

I know that using solid black color logcat in Android Studio is awful!!!

Here is my best practice colour codes that you can use for changing the face of you logcat in Android Studio to make it more useful.

Go to Android Studio Preferences and search for logcat and 'Save As' your own scheme:

**Assert**: 9C27B0

**Debug**: 2196F3

**Error**: F44336

**Info**: 4CAF50

**Warning**: FFC107

[image: Android Studio Logcat Default Colors]

[image: Android Studio Logcat Darcula Colors]

All colors are picked carefully from google **[Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html)** palette and can help you with more readability in both **Default** and **Darcula** theme:

*sharing is caring :)*

Comment: Any suggestions for *Darkula* theme?

Comment: currently I am using the same color scheme in Darkula theme, and it is wonderful. Give it a try! :)

Comment: Wow...after using it for a few days, it has been a blessing! I never knew what I was missing.

Comment: Toggle between "No Filters" and then back to "Show only selected application" to get the colors to update.  I had an annoying highlighting that was sort of stuck until I did this to get it to clear.

Comment: I would suggest to use `B87BD5` for *Assert* if you think `9C27B0` is a bit dark on the Darcula theme.

Comment: I've created file ready to import for Android Studio (https://github.com/SmithWhiteFirst/AndroidStudioLogcatDraculaMaterial)

Answer (score 24):

In addition to @Monsen Mirhoseine's answer, I exported his scheme to easier import.
You can do it by downloading [this file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/crgarridos/6029a031e6de0895c261de86f22ad6d2/raw/c1c36232ca57d214e46a78fe72118d5b29ca3645/Material.icls), and then selecting to avoid typing every color.

[image: Import Scheme screenshoot]

Comment: FYI, Before doing this, beware that the "import scheme" option does not work locally for each Color Scheme tab, (as I thougth initially). Importing the file will not only write new "Android Logcat" color features, but will also erase all other custom presets under the "Color Scheme" banner, including all your custom language colors T.T  (I am not sure if other options are also overwritten).

Answer (score 1):

You can download this files [filesCustomAndroid](https://github.com/elabi3/AndroidStudioTemplates) and copy in

Mac: /Users/.../Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioXX.XX/
Windows: C:\Users....AndroidStudioXX.XX\config\

Then go to logcat in settings and choose the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is my [Logcat custom color scheme](https://github.com/fireb86/LogcatDarculaColor) for idea / android studio:

- understated verbose log
- emphasized assert log

[image: preview]